# A question on counting non-leading monomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

To state the question I have in mind, it is necessary to define a few things. Let < be a graded monomial ordering on the set of monomials $\textbf{x}^\alpha = x_0^{\alpha_0} \cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$, and define the leading monomial of a polynomial $f(x_0, \cdots, x_n)$ to be the monomial in $f$ that has non-zero coefficient and is maximal with respect to <. Let $K$ be a field, and let $I \subset K[x_0, \cdots, x_n]$ be a homogeneous ideal. Let $\sigma_{I,m}(k) = \displaystyle \sum_{\alpha} \alpha_m$ where $\alpha$ ranges over all exponents such that $\textbf{x}^\alpha$ is not a leading monomial of any polynomial of degree $k$ in $I$. Define the Hilbert function $h_I(k) = \dim_K(K[x_0, \cdots, x_n]/I)_k$. Then we can see that

$$\displaystyle \sigma_{I,0}(k) + \cdots + \sigma_{I,n}(k) = kh_I(k),$$

and it is known that $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sigma_{I,m}(k)/kh_I(k) = a_{I,m},$ where the limit exists and that $a_{I,0} + \cdots + a_{I,n} = 1$. In fact it is known that $a_{I,m} = \sigma_{I,m}(k) + O(1/k)$.

My question now concerns a remark in the paper "On the density of rational and integral points on algebraict varities" by P. Salberger in 2007, published in Journal fur die reine und angewandte Mathematik, specifically remark 1.10 in which the author stated:

"if $I$ is generated by a form $F$ of degree $d$ with leading monomial $\textbf{x}^\alpha = x_0^{\alpha_0} \cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$, then $a_{I,m} = (d - \alpha_m)/nd$ for $0 \leq m \leq n$"

This seems intuitively clear by symmetry, but I can't seem to find a way to show it explicitly. Is there a reference that shows more detail, or can someone briefly go over the reason the above is true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the $\sigma$s and what is $h_I$?

Comment: Apparently a carefully typed out paragraph defining these things did not make it to the final copy... I will fix that.

Comment: Apparently mathoverflow cannot render < when encased by dollar signs, i.e. in math mode...

Comment: Is $a_{I,m}$ by definition $\lim_{k\to \infty} \sigma_{I,m}(k)/kh_I(k)$? If not, what is it? 

Comment: The definition can be taken as such, yes.